# Describe the phase portrait of the nonlinear system when $x'$ and $y'$ are dependent on only one of the variables

Tags: dynamical-systems

Describe the phase portrait of the nonlinear system when $x'$ and $y'$ are dependent on only one of the variables. For example, for the system $x'=y^2$, $y'=y^2$, both $x'$ and $y'$ are dependent only on $y$. Then I get that the equilibrium solution is $\begin{bmatrix} x\\0 \end{bmatrix}$ for $x\in \mathbb{R}$.

For the phase portrait, we only have the line $y=0$. When $y<0$, $x'>0, y'<0$. When $y>0$, $x'>0, y'>0$. I am not sure how to draw the $x'$ lines or the $y'$ lines on this graph. Which one corresponds to the line $y=0$? And how do you draw the lines corresponding to the other one?

Comment: Do you mean the nullclines? They are just the line $y=0$, there are no other nullclines.

Comment: Yes the nullclines, I just know what the phase portrait will look like

Comment: Well, you have the nullcline now, and so the remaining question is what happens on each side of it, i.e. if you start at $y<0$ do you approach the nullcline and same for starting at $y>0$.

Comment: But what about on the nullcline itself? When y=0, we get no information about x' or y' except that they equal zero. Does that mean y=0 has neither source nor sink on it?

Comment: Every point on $y=0$ is an equilibrium; to see whether you have a source or a sink, you need to look at $y$ close to zero and see what the behavior is. Ordinarily you would use the linearization for that but in this problem the linearization is useless.

Comment: Yes I think I drew it correctly